# Equivalent operations on instance of Ruby class (to Java)

Tags: java, ruby

I'm a Java and long-time C guy trying to learn Ruby. It's a humbling experience to say the least.

I have the following class.

```
class Node
  @@normal
  def get_normal( n )
    @@normal[ :#n ]
  end
  def add_normal( n, value )
    @@normal[ :#{n} ] = value
  end
end
```

...and I'm trying to use it probably in a way that only a Java guy would, but perhaps you can set me straight. (In Java I would have:

```
class Node
{
   private Map< String, String > normal = new HashMap< String, String >();

   public void addToNormal( String key, String value ) { this.normal.put( key, value ); }
   public String getNormal( String key )               { return this.normal.get( key ); }
}
...
Node node = new Node();
node.addToNormal( "city", "New Orleans" );
System.out.println( node.getNormal( "city" );
```

)

Below, I **think** I'm trying to get "New Orleans" out of it, but it doesn't work. (Note: On purpose I'm trying to use Ruby symbols instead of strings for the key.)

```
irb(main):001:0> class Node
irb(main):002:1>   @@normal
irb(main):003:1>   def add_normal( n, value )
irb(main):004:2>     @@normal[ :#{n} ] = value
irb(main):005:3*   end
irb(main):006:3>   def get_normal( n )
irb(main):007:4>     @@normal[ :#n ]
irb(main):008:5*   end
irb(main):009:5> end
irb(main):010:4> node = Node.new()
irb(main):011:4> node.add_normal( :city, "New Orleans" )
irb(main):012:4> puts node.get_normal
irb(main):013:4> puts node.get_normal()
```

In short, I get nothing out of this.

I would like to incorporate using Ruby symbols as keys in the hash, but the most important thing I want to learn is using a Ruby class in the way I'm using the Java class above. Or, that this is wrong-headed? If you can spare the time, please adjust my class definition and/or what I'm trying to do with it, or generally criticize. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your ruby class,

```
class Node
  def initialize
    @normal = {}
  end

  def get_normal(n)
    @normal[:n]
  end

  def add_normal(n, value)
    @normal[:n] = value
  end
end
```

and in your irb,

```
node = Node.new
node.add_normal(:city, "New Orleans")
puts node.get_normal(:city)
```

Couple notes,

- you want to use instance variables, not a class variable for something like that.  Instance variables are `@my_var` and class variables are `@@my_var`

If you leave `@normal = {}` at the class level, it'll be `nil` at the time of execution, so you put in the `def initialize` which is the constructor for the class.

Comment: This does indeed work and give me something to play with. The Googlizable samples I find seem always to come with preinitialized hashes, arrays, etc. with sample calls to print them out. I just didn't find more practical examples this afternoon. Profuse thanks!

Comment: and welcome to ruby! i myself came from Java and C++, and i am loving every minute that i play with ruby.. :)

Comment: This won't work, because you are always setting and getting the same key. Since you are both learning, I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

Comment: yes @JörgWMittag,  i'm aware of it :)  i'm only duping what OP wanted.